# How to use match and sum together in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the fields, `id`, `group_id`, `revenue` and `account`. I want to do an aggregation where the revenue is grouped by the `id`, matched with a particular `group_id` and summed up. But there will be two sums, one where the `account` is blank and the other where the `account` is not blank. How do I do this? This is what I have tried until now.

```
res = await col.aggregate([
  { $match: { group_id: "ABC" } },
  { $group: { 
    _id: "$id",
    account: { $first: '$account' },
    total_revenue: { $sum: "$revenue" }, //should be for non-empty account
    total_gl: { $sum: "$revenue" } // should be for empty account
  } }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bVQh1aOEdvb

Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get the separate the data

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      group_id: "ABC"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$id",
      group_id: {
        $first: "$group_id"
      },
      account: {
        $first: "$account"
      },
      revenue: {
        "$push": {
          "revenue": "$revenue",
          "account": "$account"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      group_id: 1,
      account: 1,
      total_revenue: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$revenue",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $type: "$$item.account"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      total_gl: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$revenue",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $type: "$$item.account"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      group_id: 1,
      account: 1,
      total_revenue: {
        $sum: "$total_revenue.revenue"
      },
      total_gl: {
        $sum: "$total_gl.revenue"
      }
    }
  }
])
```